# Time series Python Plotting Problem (Axes mismatch)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am working on water flow data, and the result is very weird with strange lines appearing in the graph.

I have read through different samples, followed the samples and still cannot get rid of these lines. Also, I change my date column to an index column but still gives me this weird graph.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? Thank you for your help.

Dataset that I use: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XpzrZ-i1c_A2XUVE4yspo5n7x0XPXwWP/view?usp=sharing

This is the picture of the dataset
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEq9g.png)

```
# combine the 'Year' and 'Month' column
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month']].assign(DAY=1))

# select only the 'Date' and 'Total_Surface_Water_Diverted' column
    df=df.loc[:, ['Date','Total_Surface_Water_Diverted']]

# change "Date" to index column
   df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
   df = df.set_index('Date')

#check out the data types of each column.
   df.dtypes

#plot the total surface water diverted per month
   fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
   fig_size[0] = 15
   fig_size[1] = 5
   plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size

   def plot_data(df):
       plt.title('')
       plt.ylabel('Total_Surface_Water_Diverted')
       plt.xlabel('Month')
       plt.grid(True)
       plt.autoscale(axis='x',tight=True)
       plt.plot(df['Total_Surface_Water_Diverted'])
       plt.show()

   plot_data(df)
```

This is the wired graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMrcf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset has around 381k rows. Your data has 13 year with 12 months each, so I am pritty sure that your data is not sorted by date monotonily. In fact I guess the date is jumping around a lot. To make this clear, if you would split this data every time a date is smaller then the one before, you would get multiple smaller sets you could draw one line each. Since you are drawing only on line in your figure, all this points are connected and this line will go back and forth, back and forth.

In the figure below you can see the that there is a gap between the years. This could mean that your data is sorted by years.
[image: gap betwenn years]

You have to figure out what your data represents and why are there multiple data point for the same year.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @mosc9575. After I sort my data, it gives me a better graph.

Comment: @carol If my answer was useful, would you please accept the answer.